# Linking nodejs server to tomcat server

Tags: node.js

I had created server in nodejs and creates routes using express....
while calling that services from tomcat server i am getting error
can anyone help me how to configure that in tomcat

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Please add the error you are getting and describe how you are calling the services from your java application

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/bears. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: That is [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) famous issue. You need to solve it from node.js side. There is package to deal with that https://npmjs.org/package/cors